# How to expose a complex type in a Delphi WebService

Tags: delphi, soap, types, complextype

I've got a problem with exposing a DTO class through SOAP WebService.

My class looks like

```
TKontrahent = class
public
    Imie : string;
    Nazwisko : string;
    Id : integer;
end;
```

Here's the Service's code:

```
TKontrahentService = class(TInvokableClass, IKontrahentService)
public
    function Dodaj( kontrahnet : TKontrahent)  : integer; stdcall;
    function Aktualizuj ( kontrahent : TKontrahent) : integer; stdcall;
    function Usun ( kontrahent : TKontrahent) : integer; stdcall;
    function Nowy : TKontrahent; stdcall;
end;
```

And how the type is published in WSDL:

```
<types>
  <xs:schema targetNamespace="urn:Kontrahent" xmlns="urn:Kontrahent">
    <xs:complexType name="TKontrahent">
      <xs:sequence/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:schema>
</types>
```

I'd be thankful for any advices. I cannot find any sample with more complex types.
Best regards,
krlm

Comment: For the sake of humanity, use English naming in your code. I'm not a native English speaker, but I'm really glad that programmers at least settled that standard. Please try to stick to that.

Comment: @Wouter: When did we settle on that standard? I wasn't aware that we had settled on any standard regarding project, unit, class, method and property names. Me thinks that maintainability and readibility is better served by using the language that is native to most of the development team... The incidental showing of code on a website like SO should not be a factor in deciding which language to use for naming your stuff.

Comment: @Marjan I agree 100% with Wouter. I had to maintain some code with naming and comments in... dutch... and it was very difficult, even with Google translate! Coding and documenting in English is mandatory. Even now, I work for a French company which has been bought by an international group, and having comments or database tables or fields in French in old code is perfectly horrible. It's a bad habit, not professional.

Comment: @A.Bouchez: While I can understand you had a hard time, I still wholeheartedly disagree with you and Wouter. When I am a Dutch shop coding for the Dutch market, it would be completely nonsensical and a waste of effort to adopt English naming just because at some future date I **might possibly** be taken over by company and that company **might** happen to speak a different language. I would say YAGNI applies here.

Comment: @A.Bouchez: Plus, many terms, especially when in the business domain, do not translate one-on-one to a different language as there may be a lot of different connotations, not to mention a completely different set of rules and regulations that go with it. As for it being a bad habit and unprofessional: well, we disagree here as well.

Comment: Late reaction, but this has to be said. :) Non-English names in code are a serious code smell. I would be wary to hire a developer that is forced to write native language variables in order to understand his own code, let alone somebody else's code. Pascal is designed to almost read like English, and if your developer doesn't have access to English documentation or 90% of the relevant websites, you're just asking for problems.  By the way, Dutch shops have **no** excuse whatsoever for writing Dutch code. I challenge you to find a Dutch speaking developer who doesn't speak English.

Comment: I'm 100% with @WoutervanNifterick. Code should be in English. You never know who might read/edit it in the near/far future. If you *really* *really* need to use your native language in code use **comments**. and yes, **"might"** is exactly the reason to do so. The OP's code showing up on SO is a "might" situation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To expose and consume the class TKontrahent in a standard Delphi SOAP service, it must be a subclass of [**TRemotable**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/InvokeRegistry.TRemotable) and its properties must be published.

As a starting point (for example after the migration from Delphi 7 to 2009) I usually import an existing WSDL to create a SOAP client and study the generated source code for classes and properties.

Comment: Thanks, Just a minute a go I found that information at: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/InvokeRegistry.TRemotable